# Best language for adding a GUI to a C++ software

Tags: c++, user-interface

I've written a C++ software that can be used from the comand line and that, obviously, can be compiled and executed in different platforms (Linux, Windows and Mac).

This software in particular is very simple, it just displays a menu in the command terminal with a few options, takes input files (.csv) acordingly, runs in a few seconds, and prints back output files (also .csv).

Now I would like to write a platform-independent GUI for it without changing my original source code.

Which is the best language? C++? Java? Does anybody have experience or recommendations on this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please **edit your question to explain what is your C++ software** actually doing, and how is it used (e.g. is it a quickly executed command, or is is a daemon or server or some HPC computation running for hours)

Comment: I hope is more clear now!

Comment: Try using CodeToGui which has a functionality to add basic gui to c++ without changing the code flow. It's pretty easy to setup and use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You will always have to change some of your C++ source code**, in particular because GUI toolkits are all event-driven so are based upon some [event-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (often provided by the toolkit library).

<sup>Alternatively, you might have the GUI be a separate program (starting your command-line thing), communicating with some form of [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) -often [pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe)- with the command line program, which you probably still would have to extend</sup>

I suggest to use [Qt5](http://qt.io/), which is a cross-platform (Linux, Windows, MacOSX, Android, ....) graphical user interface framework library for C++. If possible, use a recent version of Qt and code in [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) (since [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) become very useful).

Another approach (which still would require architectural changes) might be to make your software become a specialized web server, by using some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) (or perhaps [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)); then the GUI would be any recent Web browser. You'll probably need some web coding skills ([AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), Javascript, ...) and you'll better understand the relation between [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and web browsing. (See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/277124/40065) & [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/279861/40065)).

If your software is running quickly enough (e.g. less than some fraction of a second) you could make its core processing be a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) function (or a [Qt slot](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)) of your GUI program. But you should not have a function running for more than a few tenths of a second (otherwise, the user interface won't be responsive enough), at least not in the main GUI thread. Otherwise, split the computation in several parts or slices (e.g. "idle processing" in GUI toolkits, with [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) & [coroutines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) being a relevant concept) to be sure that the event loop is frequently (at least 5 or 10 times per second) restarted, or adopt a [multi-threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29#Multithreading) approach (with a compute thread outside of the GUI main thread), which brings painful [synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29) issues (e.g. you'll use [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)).

<sup>BTW, the good question is not the "best" *language* but to find a good-enough approach, library and framework.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, it looks a great tool ! I hope is easy to learn too ^^

Answer (score 3):

If You know C++ try [QT](http://www.qt.io),
Or look for different cross-platform GUI solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You could expose some RPC-like services, and have the front end query your C++ back end. This way you could code your UI in another language, or even expose it on a web interface.

Answer (score 2):

If you know C++ well,using WxWidgets would be good option.

Comment: I believe that using Qt would be much better, since WxWidget is just a wrapper around some other widget library.

Comment: WxWidgets give better native look in different platforms like Linux, Windows and Mac. So it is better for cross platform apps.